# Pig latinize string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an undergraduate student who loves programming very much. I met a problem when I am doing an exercise and I was confused. I had searched related files(https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/293449-simple-pig-latin-program-having-trouble/) online but I could not clearly understand yet.

The requirements are in the following:

Given a whitespace-separated sequence of words, return a new whitespace-separated sequence of words modified to be in pig latin. Pig latin here is defined as modifying a word to remove the letters before the first vowel of a word, and adding "ay" to the end of it. If a word starts with a vowel (a, e, i, o, or u, and not y), simply add "way" to the end of it. 
For Example: ball becomes allbay and I becomes Iway. Hint: the split() and join() functions may be useful here.

```
Example: 

Input: "this is a test" 

Output: "isthay isway away esttay" 

Example 2: 

Input: "how are you today" 

Output: "owhay areway ouyay odaytay"
```

My code is in the following:

```
def pig_latin(s):
    VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
    words = s.split()
    s1 = ''
    s2 = ''
    for w in words:
        if w[0] in VOWELS:
            s1 += w + 'ay' 
        else:
            s2 += w[1:] + w[0] + 'ay'
    return s1.join(s2)
```

The test cases are in the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 40, in test_hard
    self.assertEqual(pig_latin(n), a)
AssertionError: 'hriscaylustercayhrowtay' != 'ischray usterclay owthray'
- hriscaylustercayhrowtay
? --     ^        ^^
+ ischray usterclay owthray
?    ++  ^      +  ^   ++
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 33, in test_case
    self.assertEqual(pig_latin(n), a)
AssertionError: 'hisayaayofayiisayaayofaysisayaayofaytisay[472 chars]fayy' != 'isthay isway away ongerlay entencesay ofw[20 chars]yday'
- hisayaayofayiisayaayofaysisayaayofaytisayaayofayaisayaayofayyisayaayofayoisayaayofaynisayaayofaygisayaayofayeisayaayofayrisayaayofaylisayaayofayaisayaayofayyisayaayofayeisayaayofaynisayaayofaytisayaayofayeisayaayofaynisayaayofaycisayaayofayeisayaayofaysisayaayofayaisayaayofayyisayaayofayeisayaayofaydisayaayofayiisayaayofayuisayaayofaymisayaayofaymisayaayofayaisayaayofayyisayaayofayiisayaayofayfisayaayofayfisayaayofayiisayaayofaycisayaayofayuisayaayofaylisayaayofaytisayaayofayyisayaayofaydisayaayofayaisayaayofayy
+ isthay isway away ongerlay entencesay ofway ediummay ifficultyday
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 26, in test_basic_3
    self.assertEqual(pig_latin(n), a)
AssertionError: '' != 'anway emptyway indicationway ofway usurpationway'
+ anway emptyway indicationway ofway usurpationway
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 19, in test_basic_2
    self.assertEqual(pig_latin(n), a)
AssertionError: 'oareaywareayhareayaareayyareayoareayuareay[51 chars]eayy' != 'owhay areway ouyay odaytay'
- oareaywareayhareayaareayyareayoareayuareayyareayaareayyareayoareaydareayaareayyareaytareayaareayy
+ owhay areway ouyay odaytay
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 12, in test_basic
    self.assertEqual(pig_latin(n), a)
AssertionError: 'hisayalsoayiisayalsoaysisayalsoaytisayals[77 chars]oayy' != 'isthay isway alsoway esttay'
- hisayalsoayiisayalsoaysisayalsoaytisayalsoayaisayalsoayyisayalsoayeisayalsoaysisayalsoaytisayalsoaytisayalsoayaisayalsoayy
+ isthay isway alsoway esttay
```

I am very confused and thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems should be first interpreted rightly, then a using a pen and paper, try to craft an algorithm that can solve your problem. Then you can code it so that, it results in a bug free and fully functional code. Here is your code to solve the problem.

```
def fun(s):
  words = s.split()
  new_string = ""
  vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
  for word in words:
    new_word = ""
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(word)):
      if word[i] in vowels and i>0:
        new_word = word[i:] + word[:i] + "ay"
        flag = True
        break
      if word[i] in vowels and i == 0:
        new_word = word + "way"
        break
    if new_word:
      new_string += " " + new_word
    else:
      new_string += " " + word
  return new_string
```

Test Cases:

```
>>> fun("this is a test")
' isthay isway away esttay'


>>> fun("bcd")
' bcd'


>>> fun("how are you today")
' owhay areway ouyay odaytay'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what your function should look like

```
def pig_latin(s):
VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
words = s.split()
result = []
for w in words:
    if w[0] in VOWELS:
        result.append(w + 'way')
    else:
        for idx, char in enumerate(w):
            if char in VOWELS:
                result.append(w[idx:] + w[:idx] + 'ay')
                break
            else:
                continue
        else:
            result.append(w)

return ' '.join(result)
```

Since you wanted to take out all the consonants before the first vowel, you need to iterate through each word to check position of the first vowel.

Also, while doing `s1.join(s2)`, you are forgetting about adding an extra space between words.

Comment: `Input : bcd`, produces no output

Comment: @taurus05: Thanks for pointing out that use case. Modified code now.